# dygraph, plot has no lines - but does on another computer

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am using dygraph to  plot 3 variables: x, y and y2

```
dygraphs::dygraph(group_plot, main="group") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "A", drawGrid = FALSE, valueRange = c(0, 1)) %>%
  dyAxis("x", label ="B", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label ="C", drawGrid = FALSE, independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dyBarSeries('A', axis = 'y')%>%
  dySeries('C', axis = 'y2')
```

This results in a plot that has no bars or lines. However, when I remove either the bar series or the series my plot suddenly does have a line i.e.:

```
dygraphs::dygraph(group_plot, main="group") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "A", drawGrid = FALSE, valueRange = c(0, 1)) %>%
  dyAxis("x", label ="B", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label ="C", drawGrid = FALSE, independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dyBarSeries('A', axis = 'y')
```

or

```
dygraphs::dygraph(group_plot, main="group") %>%
  dyAxis("y", label = "A", drawGrid = FALSE, valueRange = c(0, 1)) %>%
  dyAxis("x", label ="B", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
  dyAxis("y2", label ="C", drawGrid = FALSE, independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
  dySeries('C', axis = 'y2')
```

I tried the first code snippet on another PC and there it works, this might be an issue with the package?

Answer (score 0):

dygraphs does not function properly on the newest version of R

I found this to be the best alternative to the plot I had envisioned

```
  dygraphs::dygraph(intercept_plot, main="intercept") %>%
    dyAxis("y", label = "A", drawGrid = FALSE, valueRange = c(0, 1)) %>%
    dyAxis("x", label ="B", drawGrid = FALSE) %>%
    dyAxis("y2", label ="C", drawGrid = FALSE, independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
    dySeries('A', stepPlot = TRUE, fillGraph = T) %>%
    dySeries('C', axis = 'y2', stepPlot = TRUE, strokePattern = 'dashed') %>%
    dyRangeSelector()
```